# rvm & duplicate environment variables (rubymotion)

Tags: cucumber, rvm, environment-variables, rubymotion, frank

I think I have a gem installed twice but I don't know how to uninstall one of them. When I try to build my rubymotion project I get these warnings:

```
/Users/pachun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/Bundler.rb:12: warning: already initialized constant ORIGINAL_ENV
/Users/pachun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/Bundler.rb:64: warning: already initialized constant WINDOWS
/Users/pachun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/Bundler.rb:65: warning: already initialized constant FREEBSD
/Users/pachun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/Bundler.rb:66: warning: already initialized constant NULL
```

And regular builds still work, but I think this is causing my test suite (frank cucumber) to fail.

How can I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to remove all gems and reinstall using rvm is do this:

```
rvm gemset empty <gemset name>
bundle
```

Instead of doing that, I would recommend you make a `.rvmrc` file and put the following:

```
rvm use 1.9.3@projectname --create
```

Save the file to your project folder and then cd out and back in to the folder, answering "Y" to the question of whether to load the `.rvmrc` file. This will switch you to a new (empty) gemset and you can re-run `bundle`.